# Reloading Python Packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package, reload

the main module sits within the runner package and executes stuff in the other packages. The main module can also **Update** the other packages and when that happens I want to reload them **in order to get the new functions/modules that were added to those packages**.

Project Structure

```
|--runner
|----main.py
|--core
|----module_1.py
|--configurations
|--utils
```

But that doesn't work.

I tried the following commands:

1. importlib.reload - only reloads a single module, using it recursively with sys.modules didn't add the new modules to the import tree. example: if after the update, "core" received a new module "module_new.py" and its imported in "module_1.py" it's not recognized after the reload.
2. I tried using IPython.lib.deepreload - it didn't work as well.

I've been stuck with this issue for some time, and haven't found any working solution yet.
Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Could you add the code you tried too?

Comment: Unfortunately the code is a protected so I cant share it, but the example I wrote is a real case. I updated one of the packages (after already running and using modules from within), and now that package has new modules which aren't recognized / loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by restarting the entire program using a while loop from an outer execution script.
Exit code 2: update required

```
    Do
    {
        $process = Start-Process python -ArgumentList $CommandLine -verb RunAs -PassThru -WindowStyle Minimized -Wait
    } WHILE ($process.ExitCode -eq 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modules will be reloaded by import command if they are not in `sys.modules` dict

```
# import some standard (non-updatable) modules
import numpy as np

# save set of non-reloadable modules on first run,
# and delete reloadable modules on other runs
if 'init_modules' not in globals():
    init_modules = set(sys.modules.keys())
else:
    modules = list(sys.modules.keys())
    for m in modules:
        if m not in init_modules:
            del(sys.modules[m])

# import reloadable packages and modules
import MyPackage
```